# How to define the operator= in a class to make a variable in it to be assigned to an outside variable

Tags: operator-overloading, c++14

I have example code and classs:

```
class a{
    int x;
    a(){
        this->x = 335; /* example number*/
    }
public:
    void operator=(int);
};
void a::operator=(int source){
    this->x = source;
}
main(){
    int i = 100;
    a example_class;
    example_class = i; //works fine!
    i = example_class; /*this is what I want to do.*/
```

}

the problem with this hole thing is that I can't
make the operator= be a friend function
therefore the command: "i = example_class"
can't be done because I can't create a function in //the the int class like I normally would with my own classes.

Finally:
How can I complete the command:
"i = example_class" when the
operator= can't have more than 1
parameter?

notes:
I know the code doesn't do anything.
And is only an example. The point
Is what actually matters.
Also, I need to make it clear that I
cannot create any functions in the
Target class(in this case int). Only in
the source class(in this case a).
I also want to make clear that I know
that it's impossible to declare the
operator= as a friend function.

I know that I could just create a function
to get a reference to int x or make
int x public but I didn't want to do that
because the real code involves complex
functions for converting between types
so it's vary important to me to be able
to write: "i = example_class;".
Thanks,
   Ronen.

Comment: It sounds like you should be implementing a user-defined conversion to int, not an assignment operator.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: Thank you but I'm a bit new to c++.
So could someone please post an example of how to implement a user-defined conversion to int in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working example](http://ideone.com/i0TqCy).

```
#include <iostream>

class a {
    int x = 355;
public:
    void operator=(int);
    operator int();
};

void a::operator=(int source){
    x = source;
}

a::operator int() {
    return x;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    int i = 100;
    a example_class;
    example_class = i;
    int j = example_class;
    std::cout << j << std::endl;
}
```